# Pandas: How to display the largest difference for a column?

Tags: pandas

I am using `(result['column1'] - result['column2']).abs().idxmax()` to find the largest difference between two columns. But it only returns the 'index' to me without actually displaying the value.

For example:

```
Breeders    number of cats  number of dogs
a                  5               25
b                  15              15
c                  25              10
```

If I use `(result['number of cats'] - result['number of dogs']).abs().idxmax()`
It would return `'a'`.

What should I do if I wanna have a output like`'a' with a difference of 20`?

Answer (score 1):

First create `Series` and then use `format` for print `idxmax` and `max` values:

```
s = (result['number of cats'] - result['number of dogs']).abs()
print (s)
a    20
b     0
c    15
dtype: int64

print ('{} with a difference of {}'.format(s.idxmax(), s.max()))
#thanks @jpp for python 3.6+ solution
#print(f'{s.idxmax()} with a difference of {s.max()}')
a with a difference of 20
```

Original solution:

```
a = (result['number of cats'] - result['number of dogs']).abs().agg(['idxmax','max'])
print (a)
idxmax     a
max       20
dtype: object

print ('{} with a difference of {}'.format(a['idxmax'], a['max']))
a with a difference of 20
```

Comment: Could save scanning `s` twice and do `s = (...).abs().agg(['idxmax', 'max'])` and then do `print('{} with a difference of {}'.format(s['idxmax'], s['max']))` maybe?

Comment: @JonClements - Yes, my first solution.

Comment: You can also use f-strings in 3.6+, `print(f'{s.idxmax()} with a difference of {s.max()}')`, more readable in my opinion :)

Comment: @JonClements - Hmmm, only thinking if mixed `Series` - numeric with string if not changed format some way ;)

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @JonClements - If use `a = (result['number of cats'] - result['number of dogs']).abs().agg(['idxmax','max'])` get mixed types Series - string `a` and numeric `20` ;) But maybe not problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
max_ix = (result['number of cats'] - result['number of dogs']).abs().idxmax()
max_br = result.loc[max_ix, "Breeders"]
max_diff = abs(result.loc[max_ix, 'number of cats'] - result.loc[max_ix, 'number of dogs'])
print  max_br + ' with a difference of ' + str(max_diff)
```